# How to resolve time out issue in rscopus?

Tags: r, http, scopus

I'm new to using APIs so bear with me!

I am trying to scrape journal articles from Scopus using the package "rscopus" in R (session info below). I have a working API and institutional key but when I run my query, it gets to about 50% completion before I get this error:

"Error in get_results(query, start = init_start, count = count, verbose = verbose,  :
Gateway Timeout (HTTP 504)"

Any idea on how to resolve this?

**Session Info**
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your request rate or number of requests is exceeding the quotas set to your account.

Please try adjusting your settings.

If the problem persists, please contact the Elsevier Data Support datasupport@elsevier.com, who may be able to help you.